# Angular: Unit Testing Routing : Expected '' to be '/route'

Tags: angular, unit-testing, typescript, routes, karma-jasmine

Am working on unit testing for my routing under my Angular app ,

My routes are delacred in a specific module which is imported under the app.module.ts ,

here is my routing module:

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { WelcomeComponent } from './welcome/welcome.component';
import { CustomersListComponent } from './customer/customers-list/customers-list.component';
import { CustomerDetailComponent } from './customer/customer-detail/customer-detail.component';
import { ApplicationParametersComponent } from './superAdministrator/application-parameters/application-parameters.component';
import { InscriptionComponent } from './inscription/inscription.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/login', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'login',  component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'login/:keyWording',  component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'welcome', component: WelcomeComponent },
  { path: 'customers-list', component: CustomersListComponent },
  { path: 'customer-create', component: CustomerDetailComponent },
  { path: 'customer-detail/:idCustomer', component: CustomerDetailComponent },
  { path: 'application-parameters', component: ApplicationParametersComponent },
  { path: 'inscription', component: InscriptionComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Here is my app.module.ts (where am used to import the routing module :

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { SharedModule } from './../shared/shared.module';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { WelcomeComponent } from './welcome/welcome.component';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { CustomerModule } from './customer/customer.module';
import { ApplicationParametersComponent } from './superAdministrator/application-parameters/application-parameters.component';
import { InscriptionComponent } from './inscription/inscription.component';

import { DxProgressBarModule } from 'devextreme-angular';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    WelcomeComponent,
    ApplicationParametersComponent,
    InscriptionComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    AppRoutingModule, /* HERE IS THE ROUTING FILE */

    SharedModule,
    CustomerModule,
    DxProgressBarModule/*,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    BrowserModule*/
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Under my test file , i followed the tuto from this blog :
https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/unit-testing/routing/

My test file for the routing testing is the following :

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
// DevExtreme Module
import {DxProgressBarModule, DxTemplateModule} from 'devextreme-angular';
// Router Modules
import {RouterTestingModule} from '@angular/router/testing';
// Services and HTTP Module
import { SessionService } from './../shared/service';
import { HttpService } from './../shared/service';
import {HttpModule} from '@angular/http';
// Routs testing
import {Router, RouterModule} from '@angular/router';
import {fakeAsync, tick} from '@angular/core/testing';
import {Location} from '@angular/common';
import {LoginComponent} from './login/login.component';
import {WelcomeComponent} from './welcome/welcome.component';
import {ApplicationParametersComponent} from './superAdministrator/application-parameters/application-parameters.component';
import {InscriptionComponent} from './inscription/inscription.component';
import {CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA} from '@angular/core';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';


describe('Testing the application routes', () => {

  let location: Location;
  let router: Router;
  let fixture;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [RouterTestingModule, FormsModule , DxTemplateModule , HttpModule ],
      providers:    [SessionService , HttpService ],
      declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        LoginComponent,
        WelcomeComponent,
        ApplicationParametersComponent,
        InscriptionComponent
      ],
      schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ]

    });

    router = TestBed.get(Router);
    location = TestBed.get(Location);

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    router.initialNavigation();
  });

  it('navigate to "inscription" takes you to /inscription', fakeAsync(() => {
    router.navigate(['inscription']);
    tick();
    expect(location.path()).toBe('/inscription');
  }));
});
```

My test fails , indicating this :

```
Expected '' to be '/inscription'.
    at Object.<anonymous> (webpack:///src/app/app-routing.spec.ts:52:28 <- src/test.ts:143891:33)
    at Object.<anonymous> (webpack:///~/@angular/core/@angular/core/testing.es5.js:348:0 <- src/test.ts:34691:26)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:391:0 <- src/polyfills.ts:1546:26)
    at ProxyZoneSpec.Array.concat.ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/proxy.js:79:0 <- src/test.ts:232357:39)
```

**Ideas ??**

Comment: Can you please add `AppRoutingModule`'s content? The problem seems to come from a missconfiguration in it.

Comment: @Supamiu O.o  it's already shared -> the first file : app-routing..module.ts

Comment: Nevermind, it seems like I had an eye bug.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You forgot to import routes to the `RouterTestingModule`, in your test file.

You have to add `export` keyword to your `const routes` in your `AppRoutingModule` file, then you can `import` the routes in your test file ( and add them in your test configuration).

```
import {routes} from '...'; // I don't have the app-routing.module file path.
...
...
...
 beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [RouterTestingModule.withRoutes(routes), <-- I added the routes here.
                FormsModule , DxTemplateModule , HttpModule 
  ],
      providers:    [SessionService , HttpService ],
      declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        LoginComponent,
        WelcomeComponent,
        ApplicationParametersComponent,
        InscriptionComponent
      ],
      schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ]

    });

    router = TestBed.get(Router);
    location = TestBed.get(Location);

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    router.initialNavigation();
  });
```

If you don't load routes in the router testing modules, it won't be able to know where to go when you `navigate`, so it will get back to original page with an error in console.

The tutorial you followed has a very strange way to handle routing because `tick()` is used for `fakeAsync` tests and this is a real `async` one. So you have to use the `Promise<boolean>` returned by [router.navigate](https://angular.io/api/router/Router#navigate):

```
it('navigate to "inscription" takes you to /inscription', () => {
    router.navigate(['inscription']).then(() => {
        expect(location.path()).toBe('/inscription');
    });
});
```

As you see you can also remove `fakeAsync` because this is not fake, it's an `async` call.

[See it on plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZoFQi4NmWT0CF3d9z7BI?p=preview)

Comment: i did it but it still fails : ERROR src/app/app-routing.module"' has no exported member 'routes

Comment: you have to add `export` to `const routes` in `src/app/app-routing.module` as I said in the beginning of the answer ;)

Comment: Still the same error Expected '' to be '/inscription'.
     at Object.<anonymous> (webpack:///src/app/app-routing.spec.ts:60:28 <- src/test.ts:233573:33)
     at Object.<anonymous> (webpack:///~/@angular/core/@angular/core/testing.es5.js:348:0 <- src/test.ts:34691:26)
     at ZoneDelegate.invoke (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:391:0 <- src/polyfills.ts:1546:26)
     at ProxyZoneSpec.Array.concat.ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/proxy.js:79:0 <- src/test.ts:232170:39)

Comment: try to change the `tick()` for a `tick(50)`, giving more time to the router to navigate properly.

Comment: even in the tuto plunkr , ofails with the same error : http://plnkr.co/edit/mTYEDNRlgGjdwv3M5b28?p=preview

Comment: i changed it to 50 and even to 100 , still failing , seems that there is another missing config to do

Comment: You need to use promises aswell, will edit the answer but here is the fixed plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/ZoFQi4NmWT0CF3d9z7BI?p=preview

Comment: thanks a lot that worked finally!! , just wanna know if there is a way to use the fakeAsync , any reference ?

Comment: fakeAsync is used for when you want to wait for a certain amount of time because you know that an async call is done but you don't have access to its promise. Here it's not necessary because you have access to it.